# WinForm DataGridView sort disables manual user sorting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

When I programatically sort a column in a DataGridView control eg.

```
dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

The user is then unable to change the sort on any other column.
How do I change the behaviour to set a default sort on a column but then allow the user to perform their own sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your columns are all able to sort when you create your grid:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
}
```

I was able to manually sort by clicking on the column headers after calling the line you gave above.  Make sure the user can sort before you call the line above.  If not, then you need to set the columnn property I show above.

Comment: I've specifically set sort mode to automatic on all columns. If I comment out the line dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending), then the user can sort the columns manually: but adding that line in, and user can no longer sort the columns. The DataGridView is bound to a DataTable.